# What's the difference between Enroll in and Sign up for?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

When I asked my native friend about the difference between **Enroll in** and **Sign up for** he gave me the following explanation:

**Sign up for**: add your name to a list or sign up for a course

**Enroll in**: get to the University and enroll on the course i.e. get the instructions on the timetable, lectures and times

That doesn't make sense to me. Does that mean the difference is between in-person registration and online registration?

Comment: At the moment your definitions aren't very helpful. It's like asking "what does however mean?" and someone saying "well however means however."

Comment: No, it doesn't. To **enrol** (one 'l') in something is to register yourself as a member of a society or a student on a course. **Sign up**, as your friend says, just means to add your name to a list. It could refer to enrolment or just putting your name down to go on a group outing, volunteer to help with a project etc.

Comment: To take things further, and for an easy way to remember the differences, you "sign up for enrolment at a university", for instance.

Comment: I think "sign up for" generally implies less effort than "enroll" (e.g. putting your name down vs paying fees), but also, as Kate Bunting says, there are various things for which "sign up" is appropriate but "enroll" is not - e.g. one-time events.

Comment: @jsw29 - I didn't know about the spelling difference, but I _did_ say that 'signing up could refer to enrolment' - but I pointed out that it could refer to other things as well.

Comment: For college classes, the two terms are synonymous. There are many other situations, of course.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of college classes, I believe these are synonymous.

More generally, you can sign up for many things that you can't enroll in. The first definition of enroll from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/enroll) is:

> Officially register as a member of an institution or a student on a course.

and it's generally only used for classes. But "sign up" is also used when registering in other contexts. Its [definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sign) is:

> Commit oneself to a period of employment, education, or in the armed forces.

For instance, you can sign up to volunteer on a project. It's not encompassed in the formal definition, but it's common to use this even less formally, such as signing up to bring a particular dish to a pot-luch party.

"Enroll" tends to be used in formal contexts, while "sign up" is more casual.

There's a similar relationship with "enlist" for joining the military.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some additional clarifications.